# Why terminal are not showing printf messages whening running win32 window

Tags: c, windows, compilation

I am running the normal win32 API, but all messages are displayed shortly after execution.
I was testing the callback of the input keys for my game and nothing happens when I press any button, but after closing the application everything goes back to normal and I have no idea what I'm doing wrong

Window file

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "./window.h"

Window wind;

LRESULT window_callback(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){
    switch (uMsg) {
        case WM_DESTROY: {
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        } break;

        case WM_KEYUP: {
            printf("SOME MESSAGE");
        } break;

        return 0;
    }
    
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

void init_window() {
    WNDCLASSA window_class = {0};

    window_class.style = CS_HREDRAW|CS_VREDRAW;
    window_class.lpfnWndProc = window_callback;
    window_class.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    window_class.lpszClassName = "GAME_WINDOW_CLASS";

    RegisterClassA(&window_class);

    wind.ws_window = CreateWindowEx(0,
        window_class.lpszClassName,
        wind.title,
        WS_VISIBLE | WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        wind.width, wind.height,
        NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    wind.ws_canvas = GetDC(wind.ws_window);
}

void update_window() {
    MSG message;

    while (GetMessage(&message, NULL, 0, 0)) {
        TranslateMessage(&message);
        DispatchMessage(&message);
    }
}

Window create_window(char * title, int width, int height) {
    wind.title = title;
    wind.width = width;
    wind.height = height;
    wind.running = 1;

    init_window();
}
```

Main file

```c
#include <stdio.h>
// #include "core/gui.h"
#include "core/window.h"

void main() {
    create_window("Game Window", 600, 600);

    while(1) {
        // if(key_pressed("A"))
        //     printf("A was pressed!");

        update_window();
    }
}
```

### Edit:

Puting an "\n" at the end of printf solve the problem

Comment: instead of `while(1)` ... `GetMessage`, use `WaitMessage`

Comment: If this is the real code then you aren't putting any newlines on the output so it is probably buffered,  try putting `\n` on the end (and `fflush(stdout);` if that still doesn't work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puting an "\n" at the end of printf solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

Win api: use TextOut() or ExTextOut() NOT printf(). You are writing to a HWND not a standard C handle.
Also Message Box() instead of printf for debug.
Next: WM_PAINT, and it's sequence BeginPaint...EndPaint. This should get you started.

Comment: OP has a console app that uses `printf` and also opens a GUI window. Both are perfectly legal. Reason why the output is not showing is most likely the blocking message loop.

Comment: HINSTANCE required for registering window class, so OP has no way to create same. besides no error checking.

Comment: Any way to link my console to window console?